# SP Classic: how do I add padding and vertical-align to list web part with CSS

Tags: web-part, css, classic-experience

The list web part contents are vertical-align middle and no padding right. How do I apply CSS to the web part? I am on SP Online: Classic Experience.

I need to clarify. What is the specific code that adds the formatting to the list web part.

The web part id="WebPartWPQ1", so I put the following into a Script Editor web part:

```
<style type="text/css">
td#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1
{
vertical-align:top;
padding-right:0.2em;
}
</style>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you save your CSS style in to a CSS file, then upload this file to Site Assets of that site/sub-site to where I need modifications and then reference that CSS file using `Content Editor Web Part` or `Script Editor Web Part` in your list view page.

```
<link href="/SiteName/SiteAssets /CustomStyle.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It will better to manage your CSS style, if you want to modify the CSS style, we just modify the file, don't need edit your list view page.